# SystemJS import an angular module but try to get and instantiate @Angular/core

Tags: angular, module, systemjs

I'm trying to load an angular component from a remote host, I'm using SystemJs to do so.

```
    this.system.import('http://localhost:3000/dist/testangularlib.umd.js').then((module) => {
    console.log(module.moduleClassName);

    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log("oups ... ");
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

my module testangularlib.umd.js is using angular as well (@angular/core and @angular/common)
When I fetch the module, SystemJS seems to try to get dependency of that module (angular/core and angular/common) but I' already in an angular app so it should find them without calling the host : localhot:8080/xxx/@angular/core

How can I tell SystemJs to use the current angular context ?

Comment: how do you build this umd bundle? if you use webpack, what's the configuration?

Comment: I'm not using webpack I'm using a yeoman https://github.com/jvandemo/generator-angular2-library